# How to test that no element should be found in protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, angular5, chai

Under a certain condition, the element should not be rendered onto the screen. Attempt to access the element gives `No element found using locator:...` which is the correct behaviour since that element doesn't exits. How can I test that the element does not exists? I tried `elem.isPresent()` and `elem.isDisplayed()` and both does not work for my purpose.

Comment: Could you please provide your code here?

Comment: `isPresent()` is what you are looking for. The function is designed to resolve whether the element exists in DOM or not. My guess is that you are first 'searching' for the element assigning to the variable `elem` what is throwing the error.. try `element(by.css('xxxxx')).isPresent();`

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the code in `try` `catch`. If the element is not found an error can be catched and false be returned. That could look as follows:

```
async function tryDisplayed(element: ElementFinder): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    var isPresent = await element.isPresent();
    if(!isPresent) {
      return false;
    }
    return await element.isDisplayed();
  } catch(error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

then in test you can do::

```
t.it('should not be visible', async function() {
  expect(tryDisplayed(by.css('your_element_locator'))).toBeFalsy();
});
```